# Suggestions to avoid "if" statement in custom functions with optional argument

Tags: r, data.table, ellipsis

Consider the following object `dt`:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(12345)

dt <- data.table(Gender = sample(x = c("Male", "Female"), size = 10, replace = T), 
           Department = sample(x = c("Sales", "Marketing"), size = 10, replace = T), 
           Hours = runif(n = 10, 6, 8))

dt

    Gender Department    Hours
 1:   Male  Marketing 7.981743
 2: Female  Marketing 6.142455
 3: Female  Marketing 7.284672
 4:   Male  Marketing 6.114810
 5:   Male  Marketing 6.067997
 6:   Male  Marketing 6.833539
 7:   Male      Sales 7.845914
 8: Female  Marketing 6.689554
 9:   Male      Sales 7.483933
10: Female      Sales 6.451656
```

Now I want to write my own function to calculate the average hours worked for the whole table or by group(s). I was wondering if the function below can be further simplified. More specifically, if I can avoid to write the `if()` statement when `...` is not used. This is what I've got so far:

```
calcMean <- function(data, ...){
  args <- list(...)

  if(length(args) == 0) return(data[, .(`Avg. hours worked` = mean(Hours, na.rm = T))])

  return(data[, .(`Avg. hours worked` = mean(Hours, na.rm = T)), ...])
}
```

Of course, this is a MWE, my custom function has a larger body but, in essence, the same concept would apply (if it can be further simplified).

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what's wrong with using this `if` statement?

Comment: do you get an error if you just pass `...` even if it's empty?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. Just imagine a larger body in this function... The `if` statement forces me to repeat the process if the condition is not met. The function gets quite larger and I find unpleasant to work on it.

Comment: `DT = data.table(x = 1:100); (function(i, ...) DT[i, ...])(1:5)` works as expected. so either your example is not capturing the essence of what is wrong here, or you can eliminate the `if` statement without trouble

Comment: @MichaelChirico This function works fine, as intended. My question is if I can simplify it by getting rid of the `if` statement and not having to "repeat" the code if the condition is not met...

Comment: @MichaelChirico Ouch, how have I not though about that? Just add the ellipsis after the statement that calculates the mean... `dt[, .(Mean = mean(hours, na.rm = T)), ...]` avoids the `if` statement. If you add it as answer I will mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: I just copied it from the body of the question! you have the power within you :p